# how to send parameters to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

So I'm using JFree chart and I'm trying to generate an image and display it in my jsp code. I would like to know how to accomplish this. I have tried multiple different ways but it doesn't work.

I saved the file and then when I try to access it. It is stored on the webserver and therefore I don't have the url to it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

I also tried to do something like this,

```
 <IMG SRC="chart.jsp"
         WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="300" BORDER="0" USEMAP="#chart">
```

which is basically jsp which generates an image. It works but how can pass parameters to it?

Comment: you need a servlet which access the resource and response to the client. save the image anywhere you like, provide a servlet for url (for example)`/img`, and in JSP points to it `<img src="/img?id=xxx"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a JSP, but a servlet to generate an image. JSPs are view components, whose role is to generate HTML markup from a model prepared by a controller.

But anyway, you pass parameters to a JSP the same way as you do for any other URL:

```
<img src="chart.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2" .../>
```

Comment: "@JB Nizet" thanks for your reply..but then how do I access in my jsp page?

Comment: Access what? The parameters? Using `request.getParameter("param1")` and `request.getParameter("param2")`. This is basic web and servlet stuff. You should read a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking of the img source as static file think of the url being a stream that will be returned from a servlet using a prticular URL

eg

```
<img src="/jfreeServer?param1=123"/>
```

Comment: how do I access it in my jsp page?